# Asp.Net Mvc Hide dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

In my Asp.Net MVC project I have two dropdownlist. My View (razor) looks as:

```
       @{
                string birth_Date = null;
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Birth_Date,
                new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)DoctorDatawarehouse.Business.CommonChoiceList.LoadYearList(), "Value", "Text", birth_Date))
       }

        @{
            string temp_birth_date = null;
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Town,
            new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)DoctorDatawarehouse.Business.CommonChoiceList.LoadEstimatedYear(), "Value", "Text", temp_birth_date))
        }
```

I want to show only one drop down. If i didn't choose from first drop down list, i want to show the second drop down list and I want to do hide the first.

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you make it clear? Firstly, first dropdown is never selected/chosen. So it will always show second dropdown.

Comment: You should specify at least in which language you're programming... Is that C#? .net? ruby? visual turbo ultra Z++ pro?

Comment: You can put a check box and toggle visibility of dropdowns. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property

```
bool IsSelected { get; set; }
```

to your model or viewbag and in your View use

```
@If (model.IsSelected) // @If(ViewBag.IsSelected)
{
    ... first drop down list
}
else
{
    .... second drop down list
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much,

i have one more question too,

in my model i mapped table to a table from my db. But isState field doesn't exist. How can i add a property to mapped model?

Comment: @Bilal: With 'IsState' you mean 'IsSelected'? I would use a ViewModel with your list data and the IsSelected property, that is set in your controller. See e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074506/2707156 for ViewModels

Comment: Firstly thank you so much, I have one more question too. In my Asp.Net MVC project I have a dropdownlist. My View (razor) looks as:   '<td><div class="editor-field">*
                <span id="span1">
            @{
                string birth_Date = null;
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Birth_Date,
         new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)DoctorDatawarehouse.Business.CommonChoiceList.LoadYearList(), "Value", "Text", birth_Date, new { @onchange = "Show()" }))

            }
</div></td>'

Comment: there is a function for my dropdownlist which name is Show(), look as:    '<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHide()
    {
        document.getElementById("span2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>'.      but i can't run this function. Where is the mistake in code?